# Renaming app name

Tags: nativescript

In my app - i'd like to rename my app for separate variations.

For Android, can I rename the app_name resource at

.\platforms\android\src\main\res\values\strings.xml

Is that the right place?

Ideally I would like the apk file to be the same - but I can rename that later.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the folder `App_Resources` under folder `App`? If so, change the app name at `.\app\App_Resources\Android\values\strings.xml`. The one that you change in `.\platform` will get override by this one every time you build the app

Comment: The strings.xml file is NOT there under the app sub-folder.

Comment: then create one

Answer (score 1):

to me it's that file :

```
.\app\App_Resources\Android\src\main\res\values\strings.xml
```

but then you'll have to quit all processes after uninstalling the app from emulator/device...
So the next time you execute "tns run plateform" it'll rebuild reaching the names set in the strings.
You have control over : Icon name, APP Title name (the action bar title)
Cheers