# Renaming NativeScript iOS Application

Tags: ios, nativescript

I need to rename my application and I'm not sure where to start. I tried manually changing the names of a few folders/files, but everything broke, I think because there were way more things using the original name than I had anticipated. I checked out the following post, but it is unfortunately for Android (I am building an iOS application). [Renaming app name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337730/renaming-app-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through the same thing recently. It was a frustrating process! I will try to remember everywhere I had to do it.

- Change the app name in your iTunes Connect account:
  Youll need to submit a new build version. Create a new version, and change the Name in the App Information section.
- You need to change it in App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist:

```html
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>NEWAPPNAME</string>
// this changes the name under the icon
```

Once youve changed that, build your app and open platforms/ios/appname.xcworkspace and make sure the Display Name has changed.

I think those are all the places.