# Renaming app name when using Nativescript advanced seed

Tags: nativescript

I'm using [Nativescript advanced seed project](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) and when I clone and run the application without any changes, application is deployed with the name "nativescript". Where it is coming from and how to change it.

Any way I can do without platform specific config?

Comment: Probably all is explained here: https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-android-apps#application-id-and-package-name If it is not, then you need to say what you have tried and what results you got.

Comment: Thanks for the above link. My question was specific to the angular seed project(updated with the link to the question). When the project is simply cloned, built and deployed to a device, it runs with the name "Nativescript" while there is no string.xml file present in the project. So was wondering if the seed project have build files to do this differently. @jdv

Comment: This clarification should be in the body of the question. Comments can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Nativescript" name is coming from the root folder name of the mobile app code (inside the project root folder). You can rename that to rename the app.

You may find adding other useful configurations(other than naming your app) when you have a platform specific configurations if add platform specific files.

Like this for Android -> https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/issues/188

iOS -> [Renaming NativeScript iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639209/renaming-nativescript-ios-application)

Comment: If these platform specific files are the way to go, was wondering why its not added to the seed project in the first place?

Comment: Had the same question. May be, its left to the developers on how they want to handle. I personally feel adding these files to the seed project. Not sure if there is any other reason for not having them.

Comment: Renaming the "nativescript" folder wont effect the imports ? Anything that I can do to avoid breaking such references?

Comment: I chose to go with platform specific files. You can try "refactoring" option if your IDE have that option(webstrom or Intellij does this cleanly) Not sure of other IDE options.

Comment: Okay. Will try. May go with platform specific files!! Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

For Android, as of `"nativescript-angular": "7.0.0"` edit or create:
/App_Resources/Android/values/strings.xml
with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">AppName</string>
  <string name="title_activity_kimera">AppName</string>
</resources>
```

For iOS, you can use the answer, mentioned above:
iOS -> [Renaming NativeScript iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639209/renaming-nativescript-ios-application)